# Pandas programming model for the rolling window indexing

Tags: pandas

I need an advice on the programming pattern and use of DataFrame for our data. We have thousands of small ASCII files that are the results of the particle tracking experiments (see www.openptv.net for details). Each file is a list of particles identified and tracked in that time instance. The name of the file is the number of the frame. For example:

ptv_is.10000 (i.e. frame no. 10000)

```
prev next   x    y   z   
-1    5     0.0  0.0 0.0 
0     0     1.0 1.0 1.0  
1     1      2.0  2.0 2.0 
2     2      3.0  3.0 3.0 
3    -2      4.0  4.0 4.0
```

ptv_is.10001 (i.e.next time frame, 10001)

```
1    2      1.1 1.0 1.0 
2    8      2.0  2.0 2.0 
3    14       3.0  3.0 3.0 
4   -2       4.0  4.0 4.0 
-1   3      1.5  1.12  1.32 
0   -2      0.0   0.0 0.0
```

The columns of the ASCII files are: prev - is the row number of the particle in the previous frame, next is the row number of the particle in the next frame, x,y,z are coordinates of the particle. If the row index of 'prev' is -1 - the particle appeared in the current frame and doesn't have link back in time. If the 'next' is -2, then the particle doesn't have a link forward in time and the trajectory ends in this frame.

So we are reading these files into a single DataFrame with the same column headers plus we add an index of time, i.e. the frame number

```
prev next   x    y   z   time
-1    5     0.0  0.0 0.0 10000
0     0     1.0 1.0 1.0  10000
1     1      2.0  2.0 2.0 10000
2     2      3.0  3.0 3.0 10000
3    -2      4.0  4.0 4.0 10000

1    2      1.1 1.0 1.0 10001 
2    8      2.0  2.0 2.0 10001
3    14       3.0  3.0 3.0 10001
4   -2       4.0  4.0 4.0 10001
-1   3      1.5  1.12  1.32 10001
0   -2      0.0   0.0 0.0 10001
```

Now the step were I find it difficult to find the best way of using DataFrame. If we could add an additional column, called trajectory_id, we'd be able later to reindex this DataFrame either by time (creating sub-groups of the particles in single time instance and learn their spatial distributions) or by the trajectory_id and then create trajectories (or linked particles and learn about their time evolution in space, e.g. x(t), y(t), z(t) for the same trajectory_id).

If the input is:

```
prev next   x    y   z   time
-1    5     0.0  0.0 0.0 10000
0     0     1.0 1.0 1.0  10000
1     1      2.0  2.0 2.0 10000
2     2      3.0  3.0 3.0 10000
3    -2      4.0  4.0 4.0 10000

1    2      1.1 1.0 1.0 10001 
2    8      2.0  2.0 2.0 10001
3    14     3.0  3.0 3.0 10001
4   -2      4.0  4.0 4.0 10001
-1   3      1.5  1.12  1.32 10001
0   -2      0.0   0.0 0.0 10001
```

Then the result I need is:

```
prev next   x    y   z   time   trajectory_id
-1    5     0.0  0.0 0.0 10000   1
0     0     1.0 1.0 1.0  10000   2
1     1     2.0  2.0 2.0 10000   3
2     2     3.0  3.0 3.0 10000   4
3    -2     4.0  4.0 4.0 10000  -999 

1    2      1.1 1.0 1.0 10001    2
2    8      2.0  2.0 2.0 10001   3
3    14     3.0  3.0 3.0 10001   4
-1   -2     4.0  4.0 4.0 10001   -999     
-1   3      1.5  1.1  1.3 10001  5
0   -2      0.0   0.0 0.0 10001   1
```

which means:

```
prev next    x    y   z   time   trajectory_id
-1  5       0.0  0.0  0.0    10000  1      < - appeared first time, new id
0   0       1.0  1.0  1.0    10000  2      < - the same
1   1       2.0  2.0  2.0    10000  3    <- the same
2   2       3.0  3.0  3.0    10000  4       <- the same
3  -2       4.0  4.0  4.0    10000  -999   <-  sort of NaN, there is no link in the next frame

1    2      1.1 1.0 1.0   10001  2 <- from row #1 in the time 10000, has an id = 2
2    8      2.0  2.0 2.0  10001  3 <- row #2 at previous time, has an id = 3
3    14     3.0  3.0 3.0  10001  4 < from row # 3, next on the row #14, id = 4
-1   -2     4.0  4.0 4.0  10001  -999  <- but linked, marked as NaN or -999     
-1   3      1.5  1.1  1.3 10001  5  <- new particle, new id = 5 (new trajectory_id)
0   -2      0.0   0.0 0.0 10001  1   <- from row #0  id = 1
```

Hope this explains better what I'm looking for. The only problem is that I do not know how to have a rolling function through the rows of a DataFrame table, creating a new index column, trajectory_id.

For example, the simple application with lists is shown here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/7020209

Thanks for every hint on pandas use,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat! This problem is close to my heart; I also use [pandas for particle tracking](https://github.com/danielballan/mr). This is not exactly the same problem I work on, but here's an untested sketch that offers some helpful pandas idioms.

```
results = []
first_loop = True
next_id = None
for frame_no, frame in pd.concat(list_of_dataframes).groupby('time'):
    if first_loop:
        frame['traj_id'] = np.arange(len(frame))
        results.append(frame)
        next_id = len(frame)
        first_loop = False
        continue
    prev_frame = results[-1]
    has_matches = frame['prev'] > 0  # boolean indexer
    frame[has_matches]['traj_'id'] = prev_frame.iloc[frame[has_matches]['prev']]
    count_unmatched = (~has_matches).sum()
    frame[~has_matches]['traj_'id'] = np.arange(next_id, next_id + count_unmatched)
    next_id += count_unmatched
    results.append(frame)
pd.concat(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understands well you want to track the position of particles in space across time. You are dealing with data of five dimensions, so maybe a DataFrame it's not the best structure for your problem and you may think about the a panel structure, or a reduction of data.

Taking one particle, you have two posibilities, first treat coordinates as three different values so you need three fields or treat them as a whole, a tuple or a point object for example. 
In first case you have time plus three values so you have four axes, you need a DataFrame. In the second case you have two axes so you can use a Series.

For multiple particles just use a particle_id and put all the DataFrames in a Panel or the Series in a DataFrame.

Once you know what data structure to use then it's time to put data in.

Read the files sequentialy and make a collection of 'live' particles, ex.:

```
{particle_id1: { time1: (x1,y1,z1), time2: (x2,y2,z2), ...}, ...}
```

When a new particle it's detected (-1 on prev) assign a new particle_id and put on the collection. When a particle 'deads' pop out of the collection and put the data in a Series and then add this Series to a particle DataFrame (or DataFrame / Panel).

You could also make an index of particles id and the next field to help recognizing ids:

```
{ next_position_of_last_file: particle_id, ... }
```

or

```
{ position_in_last_file: particle_id, ...}
```